# Ruby - Object-oriented Store example

Tags: ruby, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am starting my studies with Ruby and OO and I have received a test to do about OO.

It is a store scenario where I have to create the classes, methods, calls ...
For now I have create the class **Payment** and Product classes (Physical, Membership, Digital)

```
    class Payment
      attr_reader :authorization_number, :amount, :invoice, :order, :payment_method, :paid_at, :shipping

      def initialize(attributes = {})
        @authorization_number, @amount = attributes.values_at(:authorization_number, :amount)
        @invoice, @order = attributes.values_at(:invoice, :order)
        @payment_method = attributes.values_at(:payment_method)
        @shipping.extend Shipping
      end

      def pay(paid_at = Time.now)
        @amount = order.total_amount
        @authorization_number = Time.now.to_i
        @invoice = Invoice.new(order.get_address, order.get_address, order)
        @paid_at = paid_at
        order.close(@paid_at)
      extend

      def paid?
        !paid_at.nil?
      end

      def prepare_shipping(order)
        ???
      end
    end

class Product
  attr_reader :name, :description, :type

    def initialize(name, description, type)
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @type = type
    end
end
    class Digital < Product
        include DigitalProduct

        def initialize(name, description, type)
            super(name, description, type)
        end

        def matches?(query)
            query=="digital"
        end
    end

class Physical < Product
    def initialize(name, description, type)
        super(name, description, type)
    end

    def matches?(query)
        query=="physical"
    end
end

class Membership < Product
    attr_reader :membership_status
    include DigitalProduct

    def initialize(name, description, type)
        super(name, description, type)
    end

    def matches?(query)
        query=="membership"
    end

    def activate_membership()
        @membership_status = true;
    end
end
```

**Here is my problem:**

1.If the product is physical I have to generate a shipping label.

1.1 If its a book I have to notify that this product doesn't have taxes.

2.If the product is membership I have to activate the signature and notify via email the buyer.

3. If the product is digital I have to send a email for the buyer and give $10 discount in this product.

I am doing pretty good, but now I would like your opinion to know what is the best way following OO techniques (SOLID) to create the points above.

ps: I tried to create but my solution was really poor with many ifs.
    I think there is a better way to do it with

I have other classes if you need more info tell me please.

Sorry about my poor english.

---

I have developed this solution, I think it is good ... maybe you can give me a feedback about it.

So to solve the problem about shipping and discount rules I created 2 modules `Shipping` and `Discount`

```
module Discount

   def prepare_discount(order)
    total_discount = 0
    order.get_items.each do |item|
      total_discount += item.product.discount
    end
    return total_discount
  end

  def discount
    if matches?("physical")
        return discount_for_physical_product
    elsif matches?("digital")
        return discount_for_digital_product
    elsif matches?("membership")
        return discount_for_membership_product
    elsif matches?("default")
        return discount_for_default_product
    end
  end

  def discount_for_physical_product
      price_discount_for_physical_product = 0
      return price_discount_for_physical_product
  end

  def discount_for_digital_product
    price_discount_for_digital_product = 10.00
    return price_discount_for_digital_product
  end

  def discount_for_default_product
    price_discount_for_digital_product = 10.00
    return price_discount_for_digital_product
  end

  def discount_for_membership_product
      price_discount_for_membership_product = 0
      return price_discount_for_membership_product
  end
end

module Shipping
  def prepare_shipping(order)
    order.get_items.each do |item|
        item.product.shipping
    end
  end

  def shipping
    if matches?("physical")
        shipping_for_physical_product
    elsif matches?("digital")
        shipping_for_digital_product
    elsif matches?("membership")
        shipping_for_membership_product
    elsif matches?("default")
        shipping_for_default_product
    end
  end

  def shipping_for_physical_product
    case @type
      when :book
        create_shipping_label
        notify_buyer_product_without_taxes
      else
        create_shipping_label
    end
  end

  def shipping_for_digital_product
    notify_buyer_via_email
  end

  def shipping_for_membership_product
      notify_buyer_via_email
      activate_membership
  end

  def shipping_for_default_product
      create_shipping_label
      notify_buyer_via_email
  end

  def create_shipping_label
    puts "Creating shipping label ..."
  end

  def notify_buyer_product_without_taxes
    puts "Product exempt from taxes, as provided in the Constitution Art. 150, VI, d."
  end

  def notify_buyer_via_email
    puts "Sending email ..."
  end
end
```

This way `Product` and `Order` can extend both modules and implement the logic.

Comment: would actually be best to see your attempt, even if it has many `if`

Comment: `@order.items.each do |item| item.ship(@order) end`, and give each class a `#ship` method?

Comment: @Amadan maybe you can give to me a better feedback

Comment: @maxple This is my new solution for the problem, what do you think ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review Stack Exchange](//codereview.stackexchange.com).